# Get parameter updates applied by optimiser.step() using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient-descent

How can I retrieve the parameter updates applied by an optimisation step in pytorch? While the gradient of a parameter can be accessed by using [grad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.grad.html), e.g.

```
network.layer_1.weight.grad
```

The actual parameter update applied by the [optimiser's step method](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.step.html) will depend on the optimisation algorithm used and the current value of hyper parameters (e.g. decaying learning rate). One way of retrieving the actual change in parameters is by calculating the difference of the parameters before and after the training step, for example

```
w1 = network.layer_1.weight.detach().numpy().copy()
optimiser.step()
w1_updated = network.layer_1.weight.detach().numpy().copy()
parameter_update = w1_updated - w1
```

However, this seems computationally expensive and unnecessary, since the same quantity has already been calculated in the call of `optimiser.step()`. Is there a smarter way of retrieving the actual value of parameter updates?